# Validating app in the App Store - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to validate my application, i am going through the [doc and it says](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html)

> Before archiving your application, ensure that the binary is self
>   contained. That is, if it relies on static libraries, ensure that
>   those libraries are part of the application binary by setting the Skip
>   Install build setting to Yes in the Release build configuration of the
>   target that builds and archives the application.

After following the above step, and when i archive the app i am not seeing the archived file on the table below (in the Organizer). Why is this and how can i submit my app to Validation ? (not submit to app store, Only validation)

**Note**: When i set `Build configuration` to `Ad Hoc` it `Archives` correctly (and displays in `Organizer`), but when i set `Build configuration` to `Release`, the `archive` file doesn't get displayed in the `organizer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `Skip Install` to `YES` can be problematic sometimes, I'd only use it if you're having a specific problem that it solves. The Xcode users guide isn't as up-to-date as it should be, particularly for recent releases where the archive process has changed significantly.

Try turning `Skip Install` back to the default `NO`, and be sure to use the Product > Archive command rather than Build for > Archive.

Comment: Under what section could i find `Skip Install` ? is it in `Targets` ?

Comment: @shajem Use the search bar to find it. Didn't you say you originally changed it to YES?