# Validating app using validate in xcode - Errors found - Image provided

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I got 2 errors when I tried to validate my app with the appstore.

How could I solve this ?

The approach i took to upload my build;

When I set `Build configuration` to `Ad Hoc` it `Archives` correctly (and displays in `Organizer`), but when I set `Build configuration` to `Release`, the `archive` file doesn't get displayed in the `organizer`. I have a different [question on this on SO, but haven't got any replies yet.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862014/validating-app-in-the-app-store-beginner)

So I clicked on the `archived` file (which was obtained after I set the `Build configuration` to `Ad Hoc`), and clicked on `Validate`.

Here is the screen shot, can someone tell me what I should be doing to get rid of this error ?

**NOTE: Actually I know why the 1st error occurred, but I have no clue why the 2nd one occurred, and need guidance to solve it**
[image]

Comment: Refer to my answer. I think that should help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION TO ERROR-1:**

Make sure your app icon is added to your project bundle and Also it is exactly `57 x 57 pixels` PNG image.

**SOLUTION TO ERROR-2:**

Make sure you have set the `Distribution Certificate` and not `Development Certificate` in both `Project` and `Target Settings`.

You need to cross check it.

Also please cross check whether you are archiving the correct scheme, which you are setting the `Distribution Certificate` for.

**EDIT FOR PRIVATE KEY ISSUE:**

I have found louie's answer from the link [iPhone app signing: A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be) which was helpful to me once with same private key issue:

Here is what **Louie's** answer is:

> I had the same problem: I first downloaded my certificates to my small
>   MacBook while on the run. When trying to install the certificates on
>   my iMac... then I ran into the problems described on this page.
>
> After spending hours pulling my hair out like many of you, I performed
>   the following steps to fix it:
>
> Close all your stuff except your webpage that should be logged into
>   App Dev center.
>
> Open Xcode. Click WINDOW > ORGANIZER > select "Provisioning Profiles"
>   on the left. That should bring up your provisioning profiles.
>   Highlight one by one (if more than 1), right click and delete profile.
>   Yes, just do it! Delete them all! (I kept making a new one after a new
>   one trying to make the thing work.)
>
> From the first page you see after logging into the App Dev Center on
>   the right side click "iOS PROVISIONING PORTAL" > (do not "launch
>   assistant"). Instead click on the left side. Select CERTIFICATES. You
>   will probably have just one line listed with your name/company - from
>   there click on the right side REVOKE. Click OK to verify that's what
>   you want to do.
>
> On the same page click DEVICES. Click the box next to your device you
>   are trying to provision and click REMOVE SELECTED. Again click OK to
>   verify.
>
> Wait about 2 minutes to let Apple do their thing.
>
> Now click on "HOME" that is on the left side navigation.
>
> Click "Launch Assistant"
>
> create a new app ID - call it whatever you want. Just make sure it's
>   unique enough to know that's the one you just created because the
>   others you've been messing with all day will not be deleted from
>   Apples Dev Center.
>
> You should be able to follow the rest of the Assistant without
>   troubles -- the main thing is you just had to delete your old
>   provision profiles and start over.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @shajem: You can add the `icon files` in you `info.plist` as your <imagename>.png

Comment: When i set it to iphone distribution i get the following error : Code Sign error: The identity 'iphone distribution' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Comment: I think your problem is that you don't have the relevant `private key` in your keychain.

Comment: Is it like `Key` under Icon files --> item 0 and `Value` icon.png ?

Comment: @shajem: Check out this link for your private key problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452969/code-sign-error-doesnt-match-key-pair-in-default-keychain

Comment: You just need to set there `icon.png` if its only your iphone app and not universal app thats it.

Comment: @shajem: Please check **EDIT FOR PRIVATE KEY ISSUE:** section of my answer. I have added a link and a solution from that link which had helped me with this **Private Key** issue

Comment: I think i have just messed up my projects after i made changes here and there. I will have to try your approach once i resolve this :S . I was trying this tutorial and the whole project got messed up :Shttps://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action

Comment: In your comment you said this `if its only your iphone app and not universal app thats it. ` What do you mean ? Actually i need to distribute my app so can you suggest the best way to do this ? (This comment is about adding the icon.png)

Comment: @shajem use icon.png of 57 x 57 pixels for iphone app icon and if it is universal app you will also need to add one icon file of 72 x 72 pixels app icon for ipad.

Answer (score 0):

Well... Your screenshot says that you have some problem with your icon and codesign verification.

Icon should be 57x57 pixel, put in your app bundle, correctly added to your target membership and set in your info.plist.

Then you need an iPhone Distribution Certificate from iOS Provisioning Portal.

If you checked icon and certificate and everything it's OK, maybe **it is a problem in your uplader**: I had same problem in the past (my icon was in my app bundle, but uploader wasn't recognizing it). Try software update to get latest uploader.

Comment: What should i do in info.plist, can you please tell me how to do it. My icon image is icon.png. From there onwards what should i be doing ? Help

Comment: @shajem: You can refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494766/where-do-i-set-the-application-icon-in-an-iphone-app

Comment: Also i get the following error when i set the iphone distribution to `iPhone distribution `  error : Code Sign error: The identity 'iphone distribution' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain